# HTML5 Auto Anchor Generation When Wrapping Block Level Elements

Tags: html, markup

So this is quite interesting to me. I've got the following example markup:

```
<a href="test.html">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Hello again</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

When I have my Google Chrome (Version 26) rendering this, it shows me exactly this markup. But when I add an anchor inside the div like this:

```
<a href="test.html">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Hello again</p>
    <a href="something-else"></a>
  </div>
</a>
```

The browser outputs the following:

```
<a href="test.html">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </a>
<div>
  <a href="test.html">
    <p>Hello again</p>
  </a>
  <a href="something-else"></a>
</div>
```

So this is absolutely not what I want. I can imagine it might makes sense in order to be able to click the inner link, that the anchors are only applied to some elements, but I would need it just how i wrote it there. It makes sense, because I have to copy the inner div to another position via JavaScript. But when I do that, the code is already messed up and shows the first link.

Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I will have to add a class to the first link and then remove every anchor with that class when i clone the HTML element via jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to nest [`a` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> **Content model:**
>       Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

[Interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) is "content that is specifically intended for user interaction". For example `a`, `button`, `input`, `audio`, ….

Comment: thanks for the info! I've altered the markup now accordingly. I've used a code like `<div class="link" data-href="url.html">` now and changed the element to an anchor with jQuery.